# Rubber band scrolling on Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos

Is there any way to turn on rubber band scrolling in Snow Leopard?
I cannot upgrade to Mavericks because I need Rosetta but I would like to have the scrolling behavior of Lion, Mountain Lion and Mavericks.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**This is currently not possible.**

The question was asked on Super User too a while back:

- https://superuser.com/questions/774509/enable-rubberband-scrolling-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard (deleted, [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20140722021246/https://superuser.com/questions/774509/enable-rubberband-scrolling-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard))

Comment: The question you linked was removed, so us normal users can't see it—[here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140722021246/http://superuser.com/questions/774509/enable-rubberband-scrolling-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard) is an archived version on the Internet Archive.